# making a chart have a dotted line when there is a small sample size

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet which compares the AVG quality rating of a certain product by year. I would like that the chart google sheets makes would use dotted lines when the sample size is small (say less than 5 ratings) and a solid line when it isn't. Is there any way of doing that?
I thought of maybe splitting my data into years with and without a large sample size and then setting them to be the same color but one of the dotted line. but that seems a bit unwieldy.
Anyone know of any more efficient ways to do that

I tried playing around with the setting to make the color conditional maybe but couldn't find anything